# BizTalk 2013R2 - Ambiguous Transformation failed error

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

Seem to be getting the following daily error with an application and can't see the cause;

- Nothings changed to the mapping process within the orchestration
- Nothings changed to the content of the data being fed into the mapping process within the orchestration

> StaffApprasial.Maps.EmployeeDetails_To_SPList. Error:Transformation failed..

I've looked at the Orchestration Debugger to follow the flow, and can see where it's happening, but there's been no changes to this applications process or functionality to cause this, so I'm out of ideas as to where to look next.

Thanks

Comment: More information is needed about mapping itself. Might be mapping uses some external libraries which got affected by windows updates etc.
Also consider data changes related to encoding change.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to catch the message from the debugger contexte and run the MAP from visual studio